# Object.defineProperty: setters for dom elements properties

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I can't fully understand how `Object.defineProperty` works on dom elements.
On normal javascript objects it works like a charm

```
var obj={name: 'john'};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  get: function(){
    console.log('get value')
  },
  set:function(newValue){
    console.log('set value '+newValue);
  },
  configurable: true
});
```

the line

```
obj.name='Tom';
```

will print to console 'set value Tom' and change obj.name to Tom.

When I try it on a dom element (e.g. on the property checked of a checkbox), it will print the new value in the console, but will not change the value of the property:

```
var box = document.getElementById('checkBox1');
Object.defineProperty(box, 'checked', {
  set: function (newValue) {
    console.log('set value '+newValue)
    },
  configurable: true
});
```

clicking on an unchecked checkbox will output 'set value checked'. 
But nothing changes on screen, neither in the object box.
The setter of the checkbox just stops working. Like if I have 'disabled' it.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you've never set the value in your setter. When you create a setter, you're taking over the job of handling setting the value on the object (on the element, in your case). (And if you try to set it in your setter, e.g. `box.checked = newValue`, you'll just go into a loop that will only end because of a stack overflow.)

Looking at your code, you're trying to get notification when the `checked` property of a DOM element is changed. You can't do that with `defineProperty`. Host objects (like DOM elements) don't have to support `defineProperty` at all, and even if they do, they don't have to call the setter when the underlying state of the control changes internally.

Comment: Thank you, so is there a way (an event?) to watch the change of a property of an object in js?

Comment: @GiovanniVenturelli: What you're doing works for most objects (though you have to provide `get` as well if you want the property to be readable, and you have to store it somewhere [somewhere other than the object]), just not DOM elements. The only way I know of to handle the checked state of checkboxes is the `change` and `click` events, and polling.

Comment: Thanks again, guess I'll go with it.