# Knockout causing problems with JQuery select? Validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, knockout.js

so I'm using Bootstrap, Jquery 2.2.3, and Knockout 3.4.0. I'm having a really odd issue where a checkbox will always come back as false or undefined no matter how I select it with JQuery. I think this may have something to do with the Knockout data-bind but I'm not certain.

I'm using a custom binding in ko.js in order to manipulate the checkboxes and have the other questions produce when the box is checked.

Then validation of the rblBracedBolted is supposed to be dependent on whether the checkbox is checked or not but all values come back as 'false,' or 'undefined,' regardless of checked status.

I know the current script for validation doesn't make sense but I've tried everything from .prop to .attr and even .is("checked") etc, etc.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.checkedProp = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            Object.defineProperty(element, 'checked', {
                set: function (newValue) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value(newValue);
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            element.checked = value;
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});

$("#aspnetForm").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: { 
    <%=rblBracedBolted.UniqueID %>: {
        required: 
            {
                depends: function()
                {
                    var sel = $('[id$=cblAddlCoverage1]').val();

                    if (sel == 'Earthquake')
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

```css
.btn-default {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#e0e0e0));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe0e0e0', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<label class="btn btn-default">
<input type="checkbox" name="cblAddlCoverage1" id="cblAddlCoverage1" runat="server" value="Earthquake" data-toggle="button" data-bind="checkedProp: Earthquake" />
Earthquake
</label>

<div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="visible: Earthquake()==true">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rblBracedBolted" class="control-label">Is the dwelling braced/bolted/tied down?</label>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="padding-left: 10px">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="rblBracedBolted" id="rblBracedBolted" runat="server" value="Yes" />
                Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="rblBracedBolted" runat="server" value="No" />
                No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Feel free to ask any questions if you need more info.

Comment: You didn't include your `viewModel`, but If you'd like to know whether the element whose id is `cblAddlCoverage1` is checked, use `$('#cblAddlCoverage1').is(":checked")`.

Comment: Would the viewModel provide more answers? And I've tried $('#cblAddlCoverage1').is(":checked") it always returns false regardless whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Would the initial Javascript function checkedProp potentially be causing this?

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
Object.defineProperty(element, 'checked', {
    set: function (newValue) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(newValue);
    }
});
```

defines a property named `checked` on the checkbox element. This overwrites the vanilla `checked` property of the element. However, you never set this property value, and actually, even if you would, it [would cause an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545551/3002584).
Thus, although you may have thought that the value of the observable is set on each `set`  of the checkbox, what actually happens is that `set` is never called, because the `checked` property was invalidated.

I suggest you drop the custom binding, and use Knockout's built-in [`checked` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) (in the following snippet, I removed other attributes for brevity):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cblAddlCoverage1" data-bind="checked: Earthquake" />
```

Here's a demonstration using your html (javascript is mine):

```js
$(function () {
    var vm = function () {
      var self = this;
      self.Earthquake = ko.observable();
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<body>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cblAddlCoverage1" id="cblAddlCoverage1" runat="server" value="Earthquake" data-toggle="button" data-bind="checked: Earthquake" />
    Earthquake
  </label>
  <div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="visible: Earthquake()==true">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="rblBracedBolted" class="control-label">Is the dwelling braced/bolted/tied down?</label>
          <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="padding-left: 10px">
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" name="rblBracedBolted" id="rblBracedBolted" runat="server" value="Yes" />
                  Yes
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" name="rblBracedBolted" runat="server" value="No" />
                  No
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought that custom binding was causing issues but I couldn't breakdown what it was doing. I'm not much for JS.

Now the issue that I'm running into is when I use the bootstrap data-toggle="buttons" the checked attribute doesn't update on click. Thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer so that now it has the full demo. You can see the checkbox is working well, so I'm not sure what problem are you facing. Did you changed your code to use `data-bind="checked: Earthquake"` as suggested?

Comment: @Cloz, did you make any progress with that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, radio inputs seem to work though so after confirming it with the business I added another button with a 'none' value to toggle the input between two values which accomplished what I needed but still really odd imo.

Comment: @Cloz, well, did you changed your code to use `data-bind="checked: Earthquake"` as I suggested?

Comment: Yup, did that after deleting the custom binding and clearing the Chrome cache in order to test. With the binding gone it still didn't work. After doing some random tests in the hopes of identifying something I discovered that once the 'data-toggle="buttons"' was removed from the div it somehow started working. Problem with that was that the checkbox then didn't match the aesthetic of the rest of the page so I couldn't do that.

Comment: @Cloz, Sorry it didn't work for you. I'm sure there's something else that's causing it. As you can see, in my answer I do use `data-toggle="button"`, and it works. I think it would be fair to say that your question at its current state is answered. So it's up to you to decide if you want to mark my answer as accepted, or specify more precisely the problem and update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: The issue was resolved another way but your code snippet encapsulates the problem perfectly with a working model so I'd definitely agree. Sorry, still learning stuff, thank you for the follow up! There's definitely something else going on and I couldn't pinpoint where it could be coming from aside from the data-toggle thing. Potentially something with the CSS but like I say it has been resolved and the problem is moot at this point. Thanks you for all of your help!